# linux on arm bios-less netbook running android

Tags: linux, android, arm, netbook

I have a netbook running Android 4.0 with an ARM processor. It does not have a normal bios at the startup so I cannot boot from USB. Is there a way to load a Linux distro in it?

This is the netbook:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Notebook-Sandwich-Processor-supported-Compatible/dp/B0090463E4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ARM based devices things are not so flexible as in x86. Normally the installation process varies a lot from device to the device. They can be based on USB vendor software, install a special bootloader on the sdcard (xloader or uboot) and press a key combination to boot from sdcard ... etc.

I would recommend you to try find someone with the same device that has already replaced the Android for the Linux on your device or get a device in which people have already done that.

Replacing the Android for Linux is not simple, varies a lot and will be a pain to get all drivers working.

As an example:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40HetOQ0dQA

Comment: This may help too: http://www.techknow.me/forum/index.php?topic=5811.0